# Can we host laravel application on AWS and use all its service

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I'm creating Laravel Application with MySQL but i want to use Amazon RDS, Amazon S3 Bucket AWS Lambda, AWS Route 53 these services.

I want to know whether our laravel application can be hosted on AWS and use these services there or we have to change our laravel application structure/code so that we can use these services.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Here is one of the infrastructure, you can do better as well.

1. Upload your code to EC2 instance web root - Yo can change your code from here
2. change config settings for database connection to Amazon RDS DB
3. Use Amazon Route 53 (DNS) to refer to your public/elastic IP

Hope this will give good idea for your question.

Comment: Thanks will mysql code will work for Amazon RDS DB by changing only config settings or we have to change our internals code also

Comment: Yes Amazon RDS supports MySQL as well. Just config changes, no need of any code change.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Laravel Vapor https://vapor.laravel.com/ it is a bargain for how easy it is to use!